# Capturing linebreaks (newline,linefeed) characters in a textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea, line-breaks

I have a form with a `<textarea>` and I want to capture any line breaks in that textarea on the server-side, and replace them with a `<br/>`.

Is that possible?

I tried setting `white-space:pre` on the `textarea`'s CSS, but it's still not enough.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Have a look at the [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function. It should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 9):

The [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) function exists to do exactly this:

However, this function adds br tags but does not actually remove the new lines - this usually isn't an issue, but if you want to completely strip them and catch carriage returns as well, you should use a [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) or [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace)

I think str_replace would be slightly faster but I have not benchmarked;

```
$val = str_replace( array("\n","\r","\r\n"), '<br />', $val );
```

or

```
$val = preg_replace( "#\n|\r|\r\n#", '<br />', $val );
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to use `str_replace` or `preg_replace`, you should probably place the `"\r\n"` at the beginning of the array, otherwise a `\r\n` sequence will be translated into two `<br/>` tags (since the `\r` will be matched, and then the `\n` will be matched).

eg:

```
$val = str_replace( array("\r\n", "\n","\r"), '<br />', $val );
```

or

```
$val = preg_replace( "#\r\n|\n|\r#", '<br />', $val );
```

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting an answer that does not rely on `nl2br()`:

```
$newList = ereg_replace( "\n",'|', $_POST['theTextareaContents']);
```

or (in this case):

```
$newList = ereg_replace( "\n",'<br/>', $_POST['theTextareaContents']);
```

---

PHP Side: from Textarea string to PHP string

```
$newList = ereg_replace( "\n",'|', $_POST['theTextareaContents']);
```

PHP Side: PHP string back to TextArea string:

```
$list = str_replace('|', '&#13;&#10;', $r['db_field_name']);
```