# Post text from a text area

Tags: php, html

I have a form where a user types paragraphs into a text area and then it takes them to another page after they submit. How can I pass whatever they typed to the page after they submit? The text area might have linebreaks and if I use a query string to pass the data, it gives me an error. This is my current code to pass the field:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['form']))
    {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    header("SubmitForm.php?title=$title&body=$body");
    ?>
    <html>
    ...html form...
```

It doesn't work when the text area has line breaks in it.

Comment: You should add `exit();` after your header redirect to stop the remaining execution of the script on the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest installing a wysiwyg editor to make this easier for you, but i assume that would add some time for the learning curve.

The simplest tips I can give you is to set a CSS attribute for your textarea: [`white-space:pre`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) so that when it gets submitted, all line breaks get sent as well.
On your server side, you would need to use the [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) function, so that when it gets saved on your DB or wherever you store them, all line breaks are converted to HTML breaks.

For your additional reference, I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289159/php-capturing-linebreaks-newline-linefeed-characters-in-a-textarea) like this last year.

Comment: You might want to url encode the data prior to sending it across the URL.

Comment: Thanks... it put in the linebreak fine, but I have this in my css file :text-indent: 3em; , but the linebreak isnt indenting. Anything I can do about that? Thanks for the help

Comment: or is there a way to indent the text in the field whenever the user hits enter?

Comment: text-indent would only work at the beggining of each <p> tag. As mentioned above, a wysiwyg editor such as tinyMCE automatically generates new <p> tags for each newline so that would much help you instead of reinvinting the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be putting anything that long in a query string in the first place. Look into using [sessions](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to store data across pages instead.
(This is assuming I understood the question right)

Answer (score 0):

[urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) the data in order to pass it via query string.