# HTML Textarea reading newlines

Tags: asp.net, html, razor, textarea, newline

I have an HTML textarea that will accept a large block of text.  The textarea needs to read newlines.

For example.  If someone types the following:

---

Stack overflow is so cool.

I love it.

---

When I save it to the database and print it out again, it is shown as:

Stack overflow is so Cool.  I love it.

I need the newline (enter) to be recorded.

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What server side scripting language are you using?

Comment: MVC3, razor.  But the text area is written in HTML.

Comment: if you are using PHP, look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289159/capturing-linebreaks-newline-linefeed-characters-in-a-textarea

Answer (score 1):

Replace the HTML Text Area with CKEditor or FCKEditor Enabled control which take and save total html as per user entry for further use and display.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, you can use the function nl2br:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: lol, ok the comment about mv3c did not come up when i was replying